# Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse' not found

Tags: symfony, cpanel

I've followed the guidelines to deploy my laravel project to a host (with cpanel).
**1. I have uploaded all directories and files except the public folder to the root folder on the server

2. I have uploaded everything in my public folder to public_html

3. I have modified the URL in index.php to /..vendor/autoload.php and /..bootstrap/app.php**

I am able to access the web index now. But when I tried to access login and register or some other route I've written, a problem occurred

```
Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse' not found
```

It is even more confusing that when I tried to access simple routes, which only return views, it worked normally.

Server PHP version: 7.1

**Update**
So I tried to run `composer update` on the project directory, then `composer install`. It ran successfully, but the same error still occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `composer install` from the root of your project directory.

This will ensure all of the dependencies in your composer.lock file are installed. If you still have problems or get errors during composer install, it's likely that you haven't ensured all the php extensions have been installed on your server: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#server-requirements

Comment: I tried to ssh to my server and execute `composer install` but it gived me this error

Comment: `Problem 1
    - league/flysystem 1.0.47 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - league/flysystem 1.0.47 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for league/flysystem 1.0.47 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.47].
  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/alt/php71/etc/php.ini
    - /opt/alt/php71/link/conf/alt_php.ini`

Comment: I'm not familiar with your system so I can't tell you exactly what to run on it but you need to make sure all the required php extensions are installed and enabled, updated my answer with a link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I did it with `composer update` and then `composer install` executed on my project directory